# If $E(W) = \mu$ and $Var(W) = \sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

This is one of two HW problems that I'm positing that I have no clue how to go about.

If $E(W) = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}(W) = \sigma^2$ show that $E\left(\frac{W - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{W - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = 1$

For the first section, based on something out of the book, I'm thinking I should be able to do

$$E\left(\frac{W}{\sigma} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) = E\left(\frac{W}{\sigma}\right) - \frac{\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{\mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\mu}{\sigma} = 0$$

I'm not sure if that's correct, and I have no clue on the following part.

Comment: You're proof for the expectation is correct.
Can you tell why?

Comment: I think, your calculation for $E(\cdot)$ is correct. The calculation for $Var(\cdot)$ is "similar". You should look at the definitions of $E(\cdot)$ and $Var(\cdot)$ in terms of integrals and derive some rules about their behavior if the random variable is changed by a constant multiplicative factor or a constant additive summand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is true as you have shown due to the linearity of expectation. For the second part use the definition of variance:

$$\operatorname{var}(W) = E\left[(W-\mu)^2\right] = E[W^2] - E[W]^2$$

Then $$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = E\left[\left(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] - E\left[\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right]^2$$

From the first part you know that $$E\left[\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right] = 0$$

So $$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = E\left[\left(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}E\left[(W-\mu)^2\right]$$

But $$\operatorname{var}(W) = E\left[(W-\mu)^2\right] = \sigma^2$$

by the definition of $W$ so $$\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{W-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = 1$$

Comment: What allows you to pull out $\sigma$ like that?

Comment: Linearity of expectation. $\sigma$ is a constant. For any constant $a$ and random variable $X$, $E[aX] = aE[X]$.